# create Excel Sheet with drop down list Using EPplus

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, epplus

I'm working on Mvc web app, I want to create new excel sheet with two drop down lists filled with data from database. I want the second drop down list to be dependent on selection changed of first one. I already create file and fill drop down list but I can't find a way to make them dependent.
Any clue how to do this?

Here's my code

```
public void ExportToXlsx(Stream stream)
{
    if (stream == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("stream");
    // ok, we can run the real code of the sample now
    using (var xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(stream))
    {
        // get handle to the existing worksheet#region

        #region MyRegion Create Main File
        var worksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Beneficiary");
        var properties = new string[]
            {
                "  الاسم  ","  رقم الهوية  " ,"  رقم الجوال  ","  نوع المستفيد  ","  IBAN   " ,"  نوع الوظيفة  ","   الرتبة/ المرتبة   " 
            };
        for (var i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
        {
            worksheet.Cells[1, i + 1].Value = properties[i];
            worksheet.Cells[1, i + 1].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
            worksheet.Cells[1, i + 1].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.AliceBlue);
            worksheet.Cells[1, i + 1].Style.Font.Bold = true;
        }
        worksheet.Cells[worksheet.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();
        worksheet.View.RightToLeft = true;
        #endregion

        #region Ismilitry List
        ExcelWorksheet isMilitryddList = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("IsMilitry");
        var ismilitryValues = new string[]
            {
                "مدنى","عسكرى" ,"أخرى"
            };
        var valismilitry = worksheet.DataValidations.AddListValidation(worksheet.Cells[2, 4, 10000, 4].Address);
        for (int index = 1; index <= ismilitryValues.Length; index++)
        {
            isMilitryddList.Cells[1,index].Value = ismilitryValues[index - 1];
        }
        var addressismilitry = isMilitryddList.Cells[1, 1, 1, ismilitryValues.Count()].Address;
        var arrismilitry = addressismilitry.Split(':');
        var ismilitrychar1 = arrismilitry[0][0];
        var ismilitrynum1 = arrismilitry[0].Trim(ismilitrychar1);
        var ismilitrychar2 = arrismilitry[1][0];
        var ismilitrynum2 = arrismilitry[1].Trim(ismilitrychar2);
        valismilitry.Formula.ExcelFormula = string.Format("=IsMilitry!${0}${1}:${2}${3}", ismilitrychar1, ismilitrynum1, ismilitrychar2, ismilitrynum2);
        valismilitry.ShowErrorMessage = true;
        valismilitry.Error = "Select from List of Values ...";


        #endregion

        #region Ranktype List
        ExcelWorksheet ddList = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("DropDownList");
        var brokerBranchs = new RankTypeBl().SelectAllRankTypes();
        var val = worksheet.DataValidations.AddListValidation(worksheet.Cells[2, 6, 10000, 6].Address);
        for (int index = 1; index <= brokerBranchs.Count; index++)
        {
            ddList.Cells[index, 1].Value = brokerBranchs[index - 1].Name;
        }
        var address = ddList.Cells[1, 1, brokerBranchs.Count(), 1].Address.ToString();
        var arr = address.Split(':');
        var char1 = arr[0][0];
        var num1 = arr[0].Trim(char1);
        var char2 = arr[1][0];
        var num2 = arr[1].Trim(char2);
        val.Formula.ExcelFormula = string.Format("=DropDownList!${0}${1}:${2}${3}", char1, num1, char2, num2);
        val.ShowErrorMessage = true;
        val.Error = "Select from List of Values ..."; 
        #endregion

        #region rank list
        ExcelWorksheet ddList1 = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("ranks");
        var ranks = new BeneficiaryRankBl().SelectAllBeneficiaryRank();
        var val1 = worksheet.DataValidations.AddListValidation(worksheet.Cells[2, 7, 10000, 7].Address);
        for (int index = 1; index <= ranks.Count; index++)
        {
            ddList1.Cells[index, 1].Value = ranks[index - 1].ArName;
        }
        var address1 = ddList1.Cells[1, 1, ranks.Count(), 1].Address;
        var arr1 = address1.Split(':');
        var char11 = arr1[0][0];
        var num11 = arr1[0].Trim(char11);
        var char22 = arr1[1][0];
        var num21 = arr1[1].Trim(char22);
        val1.Formula.ExcelFormula = string.Format("=ranks!${0}${1}:${2}${3}", char11, num11, char22, num21);
        val1.ShowErrorMessage = true;
        val1.Error = "Select from List of Values ...";
        #endregion

        xlPackage.Save();
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you use `INDIRECT` in your formula as in here: http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dependent-drop-down-lists.html

Comment: Did you try this? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20259692/epplus-number-of-drop-down-items-limitation-in-excel-file)

Comment: can we disable copy paste in dropdown here