# How can I add options/values as drop downs to the header of my Excel Table using EP Plus?

Tags: c#, dropdown, epplus, excel-tables

My code creates an Excel file with columns chosen from the UI. Users use this Excel table (with only column names on the 1st row) as a template of a table and start filling details from the 2nd row onwards.

On the back end I use these input to pass through an API as a bulk upload. Sometimes, the upload fails because of the unvalidated data. There are values for certain columns. For example, a T-shirt size column has only 5 values : XS, S, M, L, and XL. But the users sometimes enter Medium and then paste the same over all of the columns. While it is not technically wrong, I want them to know what exactly they need to input.

Can I add a drop-down to the header using EP Plus? 
I also would like to validate this data on the back-end, if possible (In case they ignore the dropdown and just paste over it). But this isn't necessary, I can validate their input on upload too. Thanks in advance. Below is the screenshot of my  Excel file currently being generated...[image: 1]

and

the image of the kind of options I am looking to populate on the drop down of the Excel table...[image: 2] for the users reference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add drop down in excel using EPplus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40614881/add-drop-down-in-excel-using-epplus)